# Radio Button in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm just trying to do a simple radio button for test purposes. So I got the codes from W3School [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_radio)

I manage to create the `Radio Button`. However, after I press `save` and try out the `radio button`, I found out that I am able to check both the buttons. It's supposed to check only one, and not more than that. However, somehow I manage to check more than one.

I found out that some of the code I added earlier on have been deleted. The name attribute in the code have been deleted, and that's why I am able to check two.

How can I stop SharePoint from deleting it?

Comment: Please be more specific, what is your "actual" problem? I think I can help you out if you can be more specific.

Comment: Can you share your code?